# Using Multiple UIPicker one one screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I want to build app that will have two different UIPicker View on it. I set it all up with different variables but when I run the app I get both of the UIPicker to have the same information. What is the correct way of having two different UIPicker with different arrays?

Any Tips?

Comment: Are both of them set to use the same delegate? You will need separate delegates to populate separate controls with different data.

Comment: @Gregory Hoerner nopes, you can use one delegate for both. Simply make sure you check which one invoked the delegate method (using an if-statement).

Comment: @WTP, I apologize, I meant datasource.

Comment: Still, you can have one data source for both. Again, make sure you check which one invoked the data source method using an if-statement. ;)

Comment: Although you can reuse a datasource, my personal experience has been that using separate instances, although a little more memory intensive, helps prevent issues like this. I have created a generic array datasources when necessary, and instantiated a new instance of that datasource with an array, then assigned it to the appropriate control.

Answer (score 1):

Simply give each UIPicker a "tag"

```
pickerA.tag=0;
pickerB.tag=1;
```

and then in the data source methods add:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    NSInteger * numberOfComponents;

    if(picker.tag==0){
          numberOfComponents = 3;
    }else{
          numberOfComponents = 4;
    }

   return numberOfComponents;
}
```

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerViewPort;
{
 return 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

Well you must be having 2 uipicker object in your class as an instance variables.

In uipicker datasource and delegate methods you can check for which picker these methods are called and then load the data in them accordingly.

But if you dont have an IBOutlet for uipicker (In case you have created them in xib) then just use tags to identify the picker and load the data appropriately.

Comment: Where would I put my -(NSInteger)numberOfCompontsInPicker:......, - (void)pickerview:(UIPickerView)....., -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickervView*)......, and -(NSString*)pickerview:(UIPickerview*).....